# Search element in array

Tags: arrays, addressbook

I'm creating an Address Book program using array. I've done with the add and print data option. But now I'm stuck with the search/update option. 
This is my code in searching for the element if it exist in my array or not.

```
public void update_data(){
    String user_input_data;
    int search_data = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter the data that you want to search: ");
    user_input_data = user_data.nextLine();
    while(search_data<data_recorded){
        if(user_input_data == AddressBook_Array_name[search_data])
        {
            System.out.println("Data found!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Data not found!"); 
        }
        search_data++;
    }
}
```

But when I run the program. It always return to false and print the else statement.
I don't know what's wrong with it. Anyway the data_recorded variable holds the number of data inputted by the user in the add option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `equals()` instead of `==` in java for comparision.

```
if (user_input_data.equals(AddressBook_Array_name[search_data]))
```

Also, instead of the while you may want to use the foreach loop (removes the need for `search_data` variable).

```
for(String addressBookElem : AddressBook_Array_name) {
   if (user_input_data.equals(addressBookElem)) {
     System.out.println("Data found!");
     return;
   }
}
System.out.println("Data not found!"); // reaches this statement if data not present
```

Comment: Fixed! Thank you. I'm new to this equals() function.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use .equals function instead of ==.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you. I'm new to this equals() function.